# Ruby Class Constants

Tags: ruby

In Ruby we can find out the class methods by Class.methods, instance methods by Class.instance_method, is there any methods that lists all the constants defined in a class?

Comment: Am I missing something here?... have you just tried .constants: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001656

Comment: @Ryan: That was my bad. Please see my comment to @newacct's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Class.constants`?

Comment: I swear I tried that and it threw me no method error which is why I posted this question. Its working now. Thanks a lot. In case if a mod feels its a stupid question, please feel free to delete it.